# Javascript function only outputs value of first check box from a PHP for loop

Tags: php, javascript, for-loop

I have a for loop that forms a list of check boxes based on information received from a mySQL database. Below is the for loop that forms the check boxes (unnecessary code removed).

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($descriptionIDsArray); $i++) {
    $statuses = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT status, description FROM status_descriptions WHERE description_id='$i'")));
    $status = $statuses["status"]; ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $status ?>" <?php if ($check == 1) {echo "checked='checked'";} ?> onchange="checkBox()" /><?php echo $description ?><br />
<?php } ?>
```

Checking or unchecking a box calls the following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkBox() {
        var status = $("input:checkbox").val();
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = status;
    }
</script>
```

The only value that I can get to appear in "test" is the value of the first check box. If I echo $status throughout the initial for loop all the values appear correctly so the problem seems to arise when the Javascript code is retrieving the corresponding value.

Comment: What value are you _trying_ to get? The value of the most recently checked box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still want to keep the inline event handlers, change it to:

```
onclick="checkBox(this);"
```

And change the function to:

```
function checkBox(chk) {
    var status = chk.value;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = status;
}
```

Note that `onclick` is better supported with checkboxes and radio buttons than is `onchange`. Also, the reason for this change I provided is because passing `this` to the `checkBox` function references the element that the `click` was applied to. That way, you know that inside of `checkBox`, the parameter `chk` will be the specific checkbox that just changed. Then just get the value with `.value` because it's a simple DOM node.

Anyways, I'd suggest using jQuery to bind the `click` event. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").on("click", function () {
        var status = this.value;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = status;
    });
});
```

But you can obviously use `$(this).val()` instead of `this.value`, but why bother? If you use jQuery to bind the events, just make sure you take out the `onchange`/`onclick` inline event handler in the HTML.

You can look at why to use `input:checkbox` and not just `:checkbox` as the jQuery selector here: http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
$('input:checkbox').val();
```

it is returning the first input of type checkbox on your form, not necessarily the one that is clicked.

To return the one that was actually clicked, you need to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').bind('click', function() {
        clickBox($(this));
    });
});

function clickBox(field) {
    $('#test').html(field.val());
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to wrap `field` with `$()` as you already pass a jQuery object from the `click` handler. Should be able to just use `field.val()`

Comment: Yup, you're right, I've updated the answer.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a jquery, why bother with inline events?

You could write that like:

```
$(':checkbox').change( function(){

      $('#test').html( $(this).val() );
      //`this` is the checkbox was changed 

     //for check if item is checked try:

       $(this).is(':checked') // boolean
});
```

If you pass that code before your checkboxes are placed make sure you invoke that code when document is loaded;

```
$( function(){ 
   //code from above here
});
```

`jQuery` is well documented with lots of samples. 
I think you'll like it [docs.jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/)